# selecting n consequent grouped variables and apply the function in r

Tags: r, variables, loops

Here is example data:

```
 myd <- data.frame (matrix (sample (c("AB", "BB", "AA"), 100*100, 
 replace = T), ncol = 100))
 variablenames= paste (rep (paste ("MR.", 1:10,sep = ""), 
  each = 10), 1:100, sep = ".")
  names(myd) <- variablenames
```

Each variable has a group, here we have ten groups. Thus the group index for the each variable in this data frame is as follows:

```
group <- rep(1:10, each = 10)
```

Thus Variable names and group

```
 data.frame (group, variablenames)
    group variablenames
1       1        MR.1.1
2       1        MR.1.2
3       1        MR.1.3
4       1        MR.1.4
5       1        MR.1.5
6       1        MR.1.6
7       1        MR.1.7
8       1        MR.1.8
9       1        MR.1.9
10      1       MR.1.10
11      2       MR.2.11
 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
100    10     MR.10.100
```

Each groups means that the following steps whould be applied to group of variables seperately.

I have longer function to work the following is short example:

function considering two variables at time

```
myfun <- function (x1, x2) {
out <- NULL
out <-  paste(x1, x2, sep=":")
# for other steps to be performed here
return (out)
}
# group 1
myfun (myd[,1], myd[,2]); myfun (myd[,3], myd[,4]); myfun (myd[,5], myd[,6]); 
myfun (myd[,7], myd[,8]); myfun (myd[,9], myd[,10]);
# group 2 
 myfun (myd[,11], myd[,12]); myfun (myd[,13], myd[,14]); .......so on to group 10 ;
```

In this way I need to walk for variables 1:10 (i.e. in first group to perform the above action), then 11:20 (the second group). The group doesnot matter in this case number of variables in each group are divisible with number of variables (10) taken (considered) at a time (2).

However in the following example where 3 variables taken at a time - number of total variable in each group (3), 10/3, you have one variable left over at the end.

function considering three variable at time.

```
myfun <- function (x1, x2, x3) {
out <- NULL
out <-  paste(x1, x2, x3, sep=":")
# for other steps to be performed here
return (out)
}
# for group 1
myfun (myd[,1], myd[,2], myd[,3])
myfun (myd[,4], myd[,5], myd[,6])
myfun (myd[,7], myd[,8], myd[,9])  
 # As there one variable left before proceedomg to second group, the final group will 
have 1 extra variable  
myfun (myd[,7], myd[,8], myd[,9],myd[,10] )
 # for group 2   
  myfun (myd[,11], myd[,12], myd[,13])
  # and to the end all groups and to end of the file.
```

I want to loop this process by user defined n number of variables consered at time, where n may be 1 to maximum number of variables in each group.

**Edit: Just illustration to show the process (just group 1 and 2 demostrated for example):**

[image]

Comment: while no definite answere are comming just an idea - you can create name of variable namesmat <- matrix(names(myd), nrow = length(myd) / n, byrow=TRUE ), then apply function with myd and this matrix, but I am not sure about unbalanced data...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a function that will split your data up into appropriate lists, and apply whatever functions you want to your list.

This function will create your *second* grouping variable. (The first grouping variable (`group`) is provided in your question; if you change that value, you should also change `DIM` in the function below.)

```
myfun = function(LENGTH, DIM = 10) {
  PATTERN = rep(1:(DIM %/% LENGTH), each=LENGTH)
  c(PATTERN, rep(max(PATTERN), DIM %% LENGTH))
}
```

Here are the groups on which we will split `myd`. In this example, we are splitting `myd` first into 10-column groups, and each group into 3-column groups, except for the last group, which will have 4 columns (3+3+4 = 10).

> > NOTE: *To change the number of columns you're grouping by, for example, grouping by two variables at a time, change* **`group2 = rep(myfun(3), length.out=100)`** *to* **`group2 = rep(myfun(2), length.out=100)`**.

```
group <- rep(1:10, each = 10)
# CHANGE THE FOLLOWING LINE ACCORDING
# TO THE NUMBER OF GROUPS THAT YOU WANT
group2 = rep(myfun(3), length.out=100)
```

This is the splitting process. We first split up just by names, and match those names with `myd` to create a list of `data.frames`.

```
# Extract group names for matching purposes
temp = split(names(myd), list(group, group2))

# Match the names to myd
temp = lapply(1:length(temp),
              function(x) myd[, which(names(myd) %in% temp[[x]])])

# Extract the names from the list for future reference
NAMES = lapply(temp, function(x) paste(names(x), collapse="_"))
```

Now that we have a list, we can do lots of fun things. You wanted to paste your columns together separated by a colon. Here's how you'd do that.

```
# Do what you want with the list
# For example, to paste the columns together:
FINAL = lapply(temp, function(x) apply(x, 1, paste, collapse=":"))
names(FINAL) = NAMES
```

Here's a sample of the output:

```
lapply(FINAL, function(x) head(x, 5))
# $MR.1.1_MR.1.2_MR.1.3
# [1] "AA:AB:AB" "AB:BB:AA" "BB:AB:AA" "BB:AA:AB" "AA:AA:AA"
# 
# $MR.2.11_MR.2.12_MR.2.13
# [1] "BB:AA:AB" "BB:AB:BB" "BB:AA:AA" "AB:BB:AA" "BB:BB:AA"
# 
# $MR.3.21_MR.3.22_MR.3.23
# [1] "AA:AB:BB" "BB:AA:AA" "AA:AB:BB" "AB:AA:AA" "AB:BB:BB"
# 
# <<<<<<<------SNIP------>>>>>>>>
#
# $MR.1.4_MR.1.5_MR.1.6
# [1] "AB:BB:AA" "BB:BB:BB" "AA:AA:AA" "BB:BB:AB" "AB:AA:AA"
# 
# $MR.2.14_MR.2.15_MR.2.16
# [1] "AA:BB:AB" "BB:BB:BB" "BB:BB:AB" "AA:BB:AB" "BB:BB:BB"
# 
# $MR.3.24_MR.3.25_MR.3.26
# [1] "AA:AB:BB" "BB:AA:BB" "BB:AB:BB" "AA:AB:AA" "AB:AA:AA"
# 
# <<<<<<<------SNIP------>>>>>>>>
#
# $MR.1.7_MR.1.8_MR.1.9_MR.1.10
# [1] "AB:AB:AA:AB" "AB:AA:BB:AA" "BB:BB:AA:AA" "AB:BB:AB:AA" "AB:BB:AB:BB"
# 
# $MR.2.17_MR.2.18_MR.2.19_MR.2.20
# [1] "AB:AB:BB:BB" "AB:AB:BB:BB" "AB:AA:BB:BB" "AA:AA:AB:AA" "AB:AB:AB:AB"
# 
# $MR.3.27_MR.3.28_MR.3.29_MR.3.30
# [1] "BB:BB:AB:BB" "BB:BB:AA:AA" "AA:BB:AB:AA" "AA:BB:AB:AA" "AA:AB:AA:BB"
# 
# $MR.4.37_MR.4.38_MR.4.39_MR.4.40
# [1] "BB:BB:AB:AA" "AA:BB:AA:BB" "AA:AA:AA:AB" "AB:AA:BB:AB" "BB:BB:BB:BB"
# 
# $MR.5.47_MR.5.48_MR.5.49_MR.5.50
# [1] "AB:AA:AA:AB" "AB:AA:BB:AA" "AB:BB:AA:AA" "AB:BB:BB:BB" "BB:AA:AB:AA"
# 
# $MR.6.57_MR.6.58_MR.6.59_MR.6.60
# [1] "BB:BB:AB:AA" "BB:AB:BB:AA" "AA:AB:AB:BB" "BB:AB:AA:AB" "AB:AA:AB:BB"
# 
# $MR.7.67_MR.7.68_MR.7.69_MR.7.70
# [1] "BB:AB:BB:AA" "BB:AB:BB:AA" "BB:AB:BB:AB" "AB:AA:AA:AA" "AA:AA:AA:AB"
# 
# $MR.8.77_MR.8.78_MR.8.79_MR.8.80
# [1] "AA:AB:AA:AB" "AB:AA:AB:BB" "BB:BB:AA:AB" "AB:BB:BB:BB" "AB:AA:BB:AB"
# 
# $MR.9.87_MR.9.88_MR.9.89_MR.9.90
# [1] "AA:BB:AB:AA" "AA:AB:BB:BB" "AA:BB:AA:BB" "AB:AB:AA:BB" "AB:AA:AB:BB"
# 
# $MR.10.97_MR.10.98_MR.10.99_MR.10.100
# [1] "AB:AA:BB:AB" "AB:AA:AB:BB" "BB:AB:AA:AA" "BB:BB:AA:AA" "AB:AB:BB:AB"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to recode myfun to take a matrix and use pasteCols from plotrix package.

```
library(plotrix)

myfun = function(x){
    out = pasteCols(t(x), sep = ":")
    # some code
    return(out)
}
```

then, its very easy: for each group, compute the index of the first and of the last column you want to use when you call myfun, using modulus and integer division:

```
rubiques_solution = function(group, myd, num_to_group){
   # loop over groups
   for(g in unique(group)){
      var_index = which(group == g)
      num_var = length(var_index)

      # test to make sure num_to_group is smaller than the number of variable
      if(num_var < num_to_group){
         stop("num_to_group > number of variable in at least one group")
         }

      # number of calls to myfun
      num_calls = num_var %/% num_to_group

      # the idea here is that we create the first and last column
      # in which we are interested for each call
      first = seq(from = var_index[1], by = num_to_group, length = num_calls)
      last = first + num_to_group -1
      # the last call will contain possibly more varialbe, we adjust here:
      last[length(last)] = last[length(last)] + (num_var %% num_to_group)

      for(i in num_calls){
         # maybe do something with the return value of myfun ?
         myfun(myd[,first[i]:last[i]])
      }
   }  
}  

group = rep(1:10, each = 10) # same than yours
myd = data.frame (matrix (sample (c("AB", "BB", "AA"), 100*100, replace = T), ncol = 100)) # same than yours
num_to_group = 2 # this is your first example
rubiques_solution(group, myd, num_to_group)
```

hope i understood the problem right.

Comment: Rubique, can you show an example of how your function is applied?

Comment: you will not _see_ the output because in your example you only seem to _call_ myfun, so this is what I do, if you need just put in a list like the other answer (or in a data.frame... same thing)